# Don't understand this problem and how I use the MVT to solve it.

Tags: calculus

$$\left|\frac{1}{x^3}-\frac{1}{y^3}\right|  ≥ 48|x-y|$$

Suppose $x,y$ are in $(0,0.5)$

How do I prove this is true?

Questions I have beforehand:

1) How do I set up the MVT formula here? Is this entire expression just one function or two functions?(Or something else?)

I think that you can maybe substitute the left part of the expression?

$f(t) = t^{-3}$, so that $f'(t)=\dfrac{-3}{t^4}$

and then with the MVT:

$$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} = f'(t)$$

so... what now? Am I even on the right path?

Comment: Looks like it.  for all $t \in (0,0.5), |f'(t)| > 48$  By the MVT for all $x,y \in [a,b]$ there exists $c \in (a,b)$ s.t $\frac {f(y) - f(x)}{y-x} = f'(c)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path.

Let $f(x)=x^{-3}$ so that $f'(x)=-3x^{-4}$.  Without Loss of Generality, we take $x<y$.

Then, the MVT guarantees that there exists a number $\xi\in (x,y)$ such that

$$x^{-3}=y^{-3}-3\xi^{-4}(x-y)$$

Therefore, for $0<x<\xi<y<1/2$, we have

$$\begin{align}
|x^{-3}-y^{-3}|&=3\xi^{-4}|x-y|\\\\
&>3(1/2)^{-4}|x-y|\\\\
&=48|x-y|
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why did $y^-3$ become $y^-4$?

Comment: @user382540 That is a typo.  I'll edit.  Good catch!

Comment: How did you go from $|x^-3 - y^-3| = 3\xi^-4|x-y|$ to the next step? I'm having troubles following through from there. I understand that $0<x<\xi<y<1/2$ so why can you put in $1/2$ in the right side of the expression?

Comment: The smallest that $\xi^{-4}$ can be is $16$.